# How to clear a region (ie: a circle) in an OpenGL texture?

Tags: opengl, opengl-es, textures

I have an OpenGL texture. Is their anyway to clear a region (a circle) from it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only option (assuming you don't wan't to update the texture on the CPU and upload it) is to attach the texture to a framebuffer and render a clear shape to it. In the fragment shader you can then set whatever clearcolor you want.

Comment: Can you provide me a quick sample of how to do this ? how to render a clear shape ?

Comment: With clear shape I meant "some geometry that covers exactly the pixels you want to clear". If you want to clear a circle, render a circle.

Comment: hmm, i don't understand, because if i draw on my texture a shape with transparent color, then the background of the texture will be still visible ?

Comment: very sorry BDL, i don't see how you want to do this :( actually i can clear a rectangular area from the texture using glclear + glScissor but it's not work on non rectangular area like circle

Comment: Let me try to explain it: `glClear` does nothing else than overriding the selected region with a specific color (`glClearColor`). You can achieve the same effect when you draw something non-transparent to the texture and color it with the clear color. If you want to clear the whole texture, then a full-screen quad would do the job, but you can use any shape you want.

Comment: thanks BDL for you patience .. but i still don't understand how to set a clear color to a shape :( i can draw shape with for exemple $ffffffff color, then i have a white shape, but if i use $00000000 (null color), then i have nothing that will be drawed and the background of the texture is still here like before .. i m sure i misunderstand something :(

Comment: Have you disabled blending? The behavior you describe sounds as if you have enabled it...

Comment: dammed ! you are right it's was blending ... didn't even know this option was here and don't even know the purpose of this option ! you have a good view !!